# Iterate through regular expression array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

How can I use an array of Regex expressions and iterate that array with 'exec' operation. I did initialize an array with various regular expressions like this:

```
var arrRegex = new Array(/(http:\/\/(?:.*)\/)/g, /(http:\/\/(?:.*)\/)/g);
```

Now I created a for loop that does this:

```
 for(i=0;i<arrRegex.length;i++){
     arrRegex[i].exec(somestring);
 }
```

The thing is that this doesn't seems to work.  I don't want to use it hardcoded like this:

```
  (/(http:\/\/(?:.*)\/)/g).exec(somestring);
```

**When using the array option, the '.exec' function returns null**. When I use the hardcoded option it returns the matches as I wanted.

Comment: the exec doesn't return the matches as it should, but with the hard coded it does. matches = null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exec()` returns the match so you should be able to capture it.

```
somestring = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491489/iterate-through-regular-expression-array-in-javascript';
var arrRegex = new Array(/(http:\/\/(?:.*)\/)/g, /(http:\/\/(?:.*)\/)/g);
for (i = 0; i < arrRegex.length; i++) {
    match = arrRegex[i].exec(somestring);
}
```

`match` is an array, with the following structure:

```
{
    [0] = 'string matched by the regex'
    [1] = 'match from the first capturing group'
    [2] = 'match from the second capturing group'
    ... and so on
}
```

Take a look at this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HHKs2/1/

You can also use `test()` instead of `exec()` as a shorthand for `exec() != null`. `test()` will return a boolean variable depending on whether the regex matches part of the string or not.

Comment: I know that, and it worked beautifully when hardcoded, but returns null when I use the regex in the array like you wrote in your code. I use it on chrome browser

Comment: Take a look at the jsFiddle link I posted, it uses the array way and returns results. Or are you referring to initialising the expressions from a string? Btw, you can also use `test()` instead of `exec()` as a shorthand for `exec() != null`. `test()` will return a boolean variable depending on whether the regex matches part of the string or not.

Comment: if what you are saying is right, how come test here returns false: http://jsfiddle.net/IdanShechter/uLMBL/

Comment: @Dareen: It's important to note that `match` only retruns match groups if the regex is *non-global*.  If the regex is global, it returns an array of whole matches only.

Comment: @IdanShechter: Thats because the `exec()` modifies the properties of the regular expression object. Note that if you remove it, `test()` will return true: http://jsfiddle.net/uLMBL/1/

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want to do is to capture the first group:

```
for(i=0;i<arrRegex.length;i++){
  var someotherstring = arrRegex[i].exec(somestring)[1];
  // do something with it ...
}
```

BTW: That is my guess, not sure what you are trying to do. But if you are trying to get the host name of a URL you should use `/(http:\/\/(?:.?)\/)/g`. The question mark after `.*` makes the previous quantifier (`*`) ungreedy.

Comment: how come the test() function returns false, it should return true because there are matches http://jsfiddle.net/IdanShechter/uLMBL/

Comment: Well, your code is working here - even in Chrome. Could you give us a bit more context, like the left hand assignment of the `exec()` result. Or you could just provide your the actual relevant code you are working on.